# redundant foreign keys in PostgreSQL - are there any indexing benefits?

Tags: postgresql

Note: this is not the same as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11856022/274677) which is about adding redundant information in the tables themselves.

Does the final statement in the below series of statements buy me anything in terms of indexing / query optimization or is it totally useless and an anti-pattern? From a referential integrity viewpoint it is useless but might there be some benefit in indexing, or query processing speed for instance, e.g. in a `JOIN` only between the "child" and "grandfather" tables?

```
CREATE TABLE grandfather (i INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE  grandfather ADD PRIMARY KEY (i);

CREATE TABLE father  (i, j INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE  father ADD PRIMARY KEY (i, j);
ALTER TABLE  father ADD CONSTRAINT father_2_grandfather FOREIGN KEY (i) REFERENCES grandfather(i);

CREATE TABLE child (i, j, k INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE  child ADD PRIMARY KEY (i, j, k);
ALTER TABLE  child ADD CONSTRAINT child_2_father      FOREIGN KEY (i, j) REFERENCES father(i, j);
-- is the below statement totally useless ?
ALTER TABLE  child ADD CONSTRAINT child_2_grandfather FOREIGN KEY (i)    REFERENCES grandfather(i);
```

Comment: It's not useful at all I think. The only exception might be to help brain-dead ORMs by explicitly telling them that there is an (implicit but trusted) foreign key relationship from `child` to `grandfather` through the `father` an the other 2 FKs.

Answer (score 1):

(For similar relations simple hierarchy are more sensible... (id, parent))

Apart from that the last foreign key only slows down a bit the DML queries.

Answer (score 0):

Long answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/970605/1676382

> PostgreSQL automatically creates indexes on primary keys and unique constraints, but not on the referencing side of foreign key relationships.

...

> Therefore you have to create indexes on foreign-keys yourself if you want them.

http://mlawire.blogspot.ca/2009/08/postgresql-indexes-on-foreign-keys.html

> (Postgresql does not create indexes on foreign keys automatically).

Short answer: FKs do not provide optimization when querying--you'll need a proper index for that.

Comment: Please include the main points from those posts.  They might get deleted, moved or whatever, rendering your answer into something that lacks explanation.